# How can I do a nested loop through a variable's values and by group?

Tags: stata

I have 3 continuous variables `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and a group variable `Y`. I have a loop to summarize Xs by Y like this:

```
foreach X of var X1 X2 X3 {  
by Y, sort: summarize `X'  
}
```

Now I have another group variable `Z`: let's say it has values 1, 2, 3. How can I make the loop above run through each value of `Z` (that is, to nest the current loop into a loop of `Z` values)?

If `Y` isn't involved, then I can do like this:

```
foreach i of num 1/3 {  
foreach X of var X1 X2 X3 {  
summarize `X' if Z = `i'  
}  
}
```

But if `Y` is in, then doing the similar way, i.e.:

```
foreach i of num 1/3 {  
foreach X of var X1 X2 X3 {  
by Y, sort: summarize `X' if Z = `i'  
}  
}
```

doesn't work. It says "invalid syntax".

```
foreach i of num 1/3 {  
foreach j of num 0/2 {  
foreach X of var X1 X2 X3{  
summarize `X' if Z = `i' & Y = `j'  
}  
}  
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1347478-how-can-i-do-a-nested-loop-through-a-variable-s-values-and-by-group In any forum, telling people about cross-posting elsewhere is helpful (and not doing so is widely deprecated).

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I'll address this thing more appropriately should it happen next times.

Comment: What you can and should do **now** is close the thread on Statalist.

Comment: It seems I don't have the authority to do so, but I left a note so that a moderator can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is that testing for equality requires the operator `==`. The operator `=` usually means assignment only. (Exceptions can be seen in certain commands.)

As a matter of style and even efficiency, experienced Stata programmers would use `forvalues` rather than `foreach` wherever possible.

It is sufficient to rewrite your most complicated example:

```
forval i = 1/3 {  
    forval j = 0/2 {  
        foreach X of var X1 X2 X3 {  
            summarize `X' if Z == `i' & Y == `j'  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The `of varlist` syntax has many uses, but for an example as simple as this

```
foreach X in X1 X2 X3
```

would usually be fine.

All that said, in this example you don't need loops at all. Here is an example you can run:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
bysort foreign rep78: summarize mpg price
```